# How often the arp refresh

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

The ARP could be refreshed in 20 minutes, but in the wireshark, the packet of ARP refreshed every 20 seconds. Why refresh interval is so short？

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoO0F.png)

Comment: Systems can refresh arp entries as frequently as they like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slow ARP aging could be a problem when the MAC address changes (host or router failover, DHCP reuse, ...).

Fast ARP aging usually is no problem since each received IP packet from the IP address in question refreshes the ARP cache - with ongoing communication, no intermediate ARP requests are necessary.

So, most hosts choose to age ARP entries rather quickly.